# How to update every value of std::map?

Tags: c++

I have a **map** and **an integer** like this:

```
map<char,int>m=
{
    { 'a', 10 },
    { 'c', 2 },
    { 'e', 4 },
    { 'g', 5 },
    { 'f', 17 }
};
int a=20;
```

Now I want to update every value of map with **a**.

I've tried the following code but the values were not updated:

```
for(auto i:m)
{
    i.second=a;
}
```

Comment: `for(auto i:m)` -- The `i` is a *copy* of the pair.

Comment: You copy every value before mutating them. Reading about what are references in C++ should help you.

Comment: You need `auto & i : m` to get a reference to the objects in the map. You should consider checking [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Also: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `auto &i` instead of `auto i`.

Comment: Or `auto& [k, v]`